# Oracle 11g R2 on Redhat 6

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, software-installation

I have a Solaris background, and I am new in RHEL, and I want to install Oracle 11g on it.

I downloaded Oracle documentation, that illustrate how to install it for RHEL 6.

The following or later version of packages for Oracle Linux 6, and Red Hat
Enterprise Linux 6 must be installed:

```
binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.11.el6 (x86_64)
compat-libcap1-1.10-1 (x86_64)
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6 (x86_64)
compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.i686
gcc-4.4.4-13.el6 (x86_64)
gcc-c++-4.4.4-13.el6 (x86_64)
glibc-2.12-1.7.el6 (i686)
glibc-2.12-1.7.el6 (x86_64)
glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6 (x86_64)
glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6.i686
ksh
libgcc-4.4.4-13.el6 (i686)
libgcc-4.4.4-13.el6 (x86_64)
libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6 (x86_64)
libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.i686
11
libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6 (x86_64)
libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.i686
libaio-0.3.107-10.el6 (x86_64)
libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6 (x86_64)
libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
make-3.81-19.el6
sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6 (x86_64)
```

I tried to install each package.
I download this package: compat-libcap1-1.10-1.src.rpm

```
rpm -i compat-libcap1-1.10-1.src.rpm
```

and I got this output:

```
warning: compat-libcap1-1.10-1.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
```

And someone advice me to solve this problem:

```
    # yum install mock

and create the ‘mockbuild’ user

    # useradd -s /sbin/nologin mockbuild
```

When I tried to use:

```
yum install mock
```

I got this output:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package mock available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I can't use any one of these commands `yum` and `rpm`

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to install `-src` packages (those contain source code you need to build), try with normal ones (without the `-src` tag).

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully installed oracle 11g (few times) using http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6.php guide.

I have installed on CentOS 6.x, RHEL 6.x

When I was installing oracle 11g on CentOS there was a warning about some packages not installed. But I have ignored the warning and all things are fine. Oracle 11g can't recognise new packages so you can just ignore when the warning comes.